# Hibernate SQLGrammarException: for a table having 3 different association mapping

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I'm trying to write simple project, but I have a problem which can't solve. I searched for solution, but nothing really works. So the problem:

My guess is the problem lies int the table creation. the table order has many to one relation with first table(customer table), one to many relation with the second table(order item) and one to one bidirectional relation with the third table(addressess table). I have checked the syntax over and over again, but it seems alright for me. It should be that I am missing some thing. please help!!

The codes are listed below, with the error log.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="order")
public class Order {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name="orderID")
private int orderID;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="cid",referencedColumnName="cid")
private Customer customer;

@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name="addid")
private ShippingAddress address;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="order")
private Set<OrderItem> orderItems;

..... some for fields, constructors, setters and getters.
```

Class --> OrderItem

```
@Entity
@Table(name="orderitems")
public class OrderItem {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name="otid")
private int otid;


@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="orderID",referencedColumnName="orderID")
private Order order;

@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name="bid")
private Book book;

... More fields and constructors , setters and getters..
```

class Shipping address

```
@Entity
@Table(name="addressess")
public class ShippingAddress {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name="addid")
private int addid;

@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name="addid")
private Order order;

... More fields and constructors , setters and getters..
```

class books

```
@Entity
@Table(name="books")
public class Book {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name="bid")
private int bid;

@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name="books_author",
joinColumns=
    @JoinColumn(name="bid",referencedColumnName="bid"),
inverseJoinColumns=
    @JoinColumn(name="aid",referencedColumnName="aid"))
private Set<Author> author;


... More fields and constructors , setters and getters..
```

Code that is leading to the error...

```
package com.jlcindia.hibernate;

public class Client3 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
try{
    SessionFactory sf=AHibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
    Session session=sf.openSession();
    Transaction tx=session.beginTransaction();

    Customer cust=(Customer) session.load(Customer.class,1);
    Book b1=(Book) session.load(Book.class,1);
    OrderItem oi1= new OrderItem(1,1000);
    oi1.setBook(b1);        
    session.save(oi1);

    Book b2=(Book) session.load(Book.class,2);
    OrderItem oi2= new OrderItem(2,2000);
    oi2.setBook(b1);
    session.save(oi2);

    ShippingAddress add= new ShippingAddress("AMP","HYD","AP");
    session.save(add);
    Set<OrderItem> orderItems= new HashSet<OrderItem>();
    orderItems.add(oi1);
    orderItems.add(oi2);

    Order order= new Order(3,3000.0, new Date(),"New");
    order.setAddress(add);
    order.setOrderItems(orderItems);
    order.setCustomer(cust);
    session.save(order);


    tx.commit();
    session.close();

}catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}
}
```

the created table will be having many to one mapping for customer table and one to mapping for addressess table and one to many for orderItems.

The Exception that i am getting is :

```
org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not insert: [com.jlcindia.hibernate.Order]
...............
................
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Syntax error or access violation,  message from server: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'order (addid, cid, orderDate, status, totalCost, totalqty) values (2, 1, '2014-0' at line 1"
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:1977)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1163)
... 16 more
```

I am not able to get this. In-fact, I am not even understanding where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had this same problem years ago... it's so silly and simple...

You can't put `order` as name to a table in Hibernate + MySQL with annotations, since `order` is a reserved word in MySQL.

You could check if this is the problem easily changing `order` to `order_` by example.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Wow, Thanks a lot, I was going nuts over this. I was quite sure that all the mappings were right. but still I was getting this exception.

Thank you..